# Couldn't get tq_exchange() or stockSymbols() to work

Tags: r

I am trying to get stock symbols with these functions (both failed)

```
TTR::stockSymbols("AMEX")
```

> Error in symbols[, sort.by] : incorrect number of dimensions

```
tidyquant::tq_exchange("AMEX")
```

> Getting data...
>
> Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.
> x Column `Symbol` doesn't exist.

Do these functions work for you?  What fixes do you know to correct them?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. It seems like there has been some changes in the website from which these packages get the information. There is an [open issue about this](https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant/issues/190).

In the same thread it is mentioned that you can get the information from the underlying JSON which returns this information.

```
tmp <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&exchange=AMEX&download=true')
head(tmp$data$rows)

#  symbol                                                           name
#1   AAMC                           Altisource Asset Management Corp Com
#2    AAU                            Almaden Minerals Ltd. Common Shares
#3    ACU                          Acme United Corporation. Common Stock
#4    ACY                                 AeroCentury Corp. Common Stock
#5     AE                     Adams Resources & Energy Inc. Common Stock
#6    AEF Aberdeen Emerging Markets Equity Income Fund Inc. Common Stock

#  lastsale netchange pctchange  volume    marketCap       country ipoyear
#1   $24.60   -0.3595    -1.44%   15183  40595215.00 United States        
#2   $0.846    0.0359    4.432% 2272603 101984125.00        Canada    2015
#3   $33.82      0.61    1.837%    7869 112922038.00 United States    1988
#4   $11.76      2.01   20.615%  739133  18179596.00 United States        
#5   $28.31      0.11     0.39%    6217 120099060.00 United States        
#6    $9.10      0.09    0.999%   40775 461841180.00 United States  
      
#                         industry           sector
#1                     Real Estate          Finance
#2                 Precious Metals Basic Industries
#3 Industrial Machinery/Components    Capital Goods
#4 Diversified Commercial Services       Technology
#5          Oil Refining/Marketing           Energy
#6                                                 

#                           url
#1 /market-activity/stocks/aamc
#2  /market-activity/stocks/aau
#3  /market-activity/stocks/acu
#4  /market-activity/stocks/acy
#5   /market-activity/stocks/ae
#6  /market-activity/stocks/aef
```

Comment: Thanks!   It looks like the developer of "tidyquant" package is too busy to fix this.  I will try the json solution for now.